Found illegal assignment group name conflicts with top-level node name
How to fix the follow errors was appeared after pin assingment (in Pin Planner window) and project compilation:

"Error: Found illegal assignment group name "key" -- conflicts with top-level node name";
"Error: Found illegal assignment group name "led" -- conflicts with top-level node name".

Processing messanges:

Top-level VHDL:
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity led_switch is
port(
    key:in std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
    led:out std_logic_vector(9 downto 0));
end led_switch;

architecture myArc of led_switch is
    signal Y: std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
begin

process(key,Y)
begin
    Y(0) <= key(0);
    Y(1) <= key(1);
    Y(2) <= key(2);
    Y(3) <= key(3);
    Y(4) <= key(4);
    Y(5) <= key(5);
    Y(6) <= key(6);
    Y(7) <= key(7);
    Y(8) <= key(8);
    Y(9) <= key(9);
    led <= Y;
end process;

end myArc;

Pin Planner window:

Also, I did assignments' export in .QSF file:
Is exported QSF file
I work in Quartus II 9.0 (Build 132 02/25/2009 SJ Web Edition) and use the device Cyclone III (EP3C16F484C6).
What I tried to do already:

I attempted to change name of key group (named as "key[9..0]" by default now) on "keyGroup" in Pin Planner window, but after name chaging all the group's pins disappeared (to do it visible again need to execute the command "Refresh" in the View tab of Pin Planner window).
Also, I renamed "key" group in "keyGroup" and "led" in "ledGroup". It was did in exported assignments' QSF file. After that, was imported changed QSF file in Quartus, but it did not change situation – the same errors remaided.
But, as soon as I exported changed QSF file, I imported it and got original (before groups' name changing) file. This may indicate the QSF file wasn't exported actually...


Remove the process start/end statements, just leave the 11 assignments. Then try compiling it again.

@TonyM, No, it don't work. The same errors appear.

OK, then the problem's most likely in your constraints so post your project's QSF file. While you're editing your post, rephrase it to ask an actual specific question - it's just a statement at the moment.

@TonyM, I added the QSF file

Having looked through it, get rid of all those ASSIGNMENT_GROUP_MEMBER constraints then try again. Delete them directly from the QSF, you don't need them.

What happened when you deleted all the ASSIGNMENT_GROUP_MEMBER constraints from the QSF? Why were they even there, why had you created them (via the GUI) ?

Was changed automatically generated QSF file by the Pin Planner in the work folder of the project. Namely, was replaced "key" strings by "keyGroup" and "led" strings by "ledGroup" (i.e. was renamed pin groups).
